# ng-show inside ng-repeat instance not working

Tags: angularjs

Can someone help me figure out how to make this ng-show work within an ng-repeat item? Sometimes there is an "nNumber" and sometimes not but ng-show isn't triggering. I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it to work. Thank you in advance.

```
<option ng-repeat="asset in assets" value="{{asset.id}}">
{{asset.assetName}} 
<span ng-show="asset.nNumber">({{asset.nNumber| uppercase}})</span>
</option>
```

Comment: Try inspecting the scope to see what is actually there. `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk` - Chrome, `https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/` - Firefox

Comment: This is cool...haven't used that...i'll check this out and hopefully this can help me troubleshoot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) works on boolean value if its true , I guess nNumber is not a boolean value.If it's not a boolean value you need to check whether its null,

```
<span ng-show="asset.nNumber !=null">({{asset.nNumber| uppercase}})</span>
```

Comment: If `nNumber` is not a boolean, angular will show `span` if `nNumber` is defined. Without any directive/controller code, it's hard to get appropriate answer.

Comment: Correct...nNumber is a number and is not a boolean. It is coming from a DB and sometimes has values and sometimes it doesn't. I think the problem may be that it comes in as empty instead of null. Perhaps?

Comment: so you want it to show if the number is greater than 0? Also.. what's up with the uppercase if it's a number (just curious)?

Comment: I apologize I mispoke...it can also include letters so it's a string not a number. Uppercase just makes it all uppercase in case of lower case letters.

Comment: And it sometimes could be equal to `null`?

Comment: Yes... can be null, "", or "A12323" or "234234"

Comment: if it's null or "" you don't want it to show, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if it's undefined: it will cover the case the property it's not present in the asset object.

```
<span ng-show="asset.nNumber != null">({{asset.nNumber| uppercase}})</span>
```

You should also consider using ng-if: why using a filter to nNumber (and hiding it) in the case the property doesn't exist? With ng-if you will remove it from dom, and it will not apply any filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, if it's OK to also hide it if the value is `0`.

```
<option ng-repeat="asset in assets" value="{{asset.id}}">
    {{asset.assetName}} 
    <span ng-show="!!asset.nNumber">({{asset.nNumber| uppercase}})</span>
</option>
```

Comment: @sstrick It means there is another problem. Based on the code we can see this is how far we can get.